# Is [navigation] just [cursor-movement]?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

The [cursor-movement](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cursor-movement) tag has 194 questions.

The [navigation](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/navigation) tag has 37 questions, and no tag wiki.

Should [navigation](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/navigation) be made a synonym of [cursor-movement](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cursor-movement)?  Or should it mean something distinct (switching tabs or buffers, perhaps?), with its intended usage clarified?

Comment: Personally I would use `navigation` for questions about navigating a code base or a file system (using tags, quickfix list, marks, finding files, etc) and `cursor-movement` for questions about moving the cursor in a buffer or through windows, typically the stuff in [`:h cursor-motions`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#cursor-motions). However the tagged questions doesn't really reflect that and in the doc [`:h navigation`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#navigation) and `:h cursor-motions` are synonyms, so it would also make sense to merge them.

Comment: [My answer here](https://vi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1456/51) applies to this case too: I don't think it really matters.

Comment: @statox at least one of the navigation questions is about cscope. But as Martin says, these tags dont really connect experts with questions to answer.