# Map [keymap] to [key-bindings]

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

I recently hit 4000 rep  and decided to go tag-wiki hunting. On the rep page, there's a link to this [2011 blog post on tags](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/03/24/redesigned-tags-page/) which suggests really cleaning up at least the first two pages. Ok, says I, two pages isn't so bad.

I stumbled across [keymap](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/keymap) with no wiki, but looking at the questions it seems too similar to [key-bindings](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/key-bindings), which overwhelmingly has more questions.

[Synonymize?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms?tab=Newest&filter=Suggested)

Comment: +1, especially since [tag:key-mappings], [tag:mappings], and [tag:map] synonymized to key-bindings.

Comment: Agreed too +1 :)

Answer (score 2):

The `keymap` tag was intended for the `keymap` setting, which is not the same as a key binding (or key mapping). Of course, people use tags wrong all the time, so many questions were probably mistagged, but it's not the same thing.

Comment: Hmm. Perhaps a new, clearer tag is needed? Or, keymap needs a new wiki, and we need to retag some old questions based on the difference?

Comment: Maybe @D.BenKnoble ... To be honest, I've mostly given up on tagging. I spent a lot of time on this and the Poitics.SE site attempting to clean up tags, and in Dutch we would call it "mopping the floor with the tap running", the meaning of which should be easy to deduce ;-) I'm also not so sure of the value of most tags on this site (see [previous answer](https://vi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1456/51)).

Answer (score 0):

This has been done, with enough votes. You can see [keymap](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/keymap) to verify for yourself.