# Airline tag name

Tags: discussion, tags

[plugin-airline](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plugin-airline) has few (3) questions, while [plugin-vim-airline](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plugin-vim-airline) has many (45).

Before I go about suggesting synonyms or whatever (on Meta, since I cannot do so myself), I wanted to clarify what the naming convention was.

Most plugins I see use the [plugin-name](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plugin-name) convention. The only reason I could see airline being different is that its GitHub name is officially [vim-airline/vim-airline](https://github.com/vim-airline/vim-airline). And yet, many plugins do strange things with their names (I've seen `name.vim`, `vim-name`, `name-vim`, `name-nvim`, etc.) that I don’t see represented this way.

Thoughts?

Personally, I’d like to unify the tags, I’m just not sure which one is the best “canonical” tag.

---

In light of Martin's resignation, I'll attempt to address his usual counter-argument: cleaning up tags is like bailing water out of a boat with a hole in the bottom.

While I agree that it's impossible to ever keep up completely, I would rather see us keep the tag system well-oiled every now and then than ignore its slow death—I don't use the tags to find things often (on this site—on others, that's not as true). But *someone* may.

(Apologies to Martin if I've mis-represented his stance.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I usually omit the "vim" part in tag names unless it's an important part of the plugin name (e.g. "vim-go", "vimwiki"). This essentially follows how people would talk about plugins in person: you would say "vim-go" and "vimwiki", but "airline" and "surround".

The tag naming we have now isn't fully consistent, with "vim" sometimes being elided and sometimes not, It is what it is

I merged the two tags and created a synonym, with [plugin-airline](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plugin-airline) as the target (this can be easily swapped if people strongly feel it should have been the reverse). Regardless of which name is chosen, having just one tag is certainly an improvement.

> I'll attempt to address his usual counter-argument: cleaning up tags is like bailing water out of a boat with a hole in the bottom.

Much depends on *which* tags: [in my previous answer](https://vi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1456/51) I explicitly pointed out the usefulness of tags for plugins; I just don't see much value in tags for general Vim features like cursor movement and whatnot.

Comment: Another day of learning, as always :) thanks