# Tags for compilation related questions

Tags: discussion

When answering [How can i compile cpp using vim](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/28759/how-can-i-compile-cpp-using-vim) yesterday, I've seen that there was no tag related to *compilation from vim* associated to the question.

So, "*let's add one*" I though. I've started to type `compi` to see [compile-vim](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/compile-vim) being proposed. "*Okay, that's an odd one*", I check what questions are associated to it, and I see: questions about compiling from vim, and also questions about compiling Vim, and no description.

**First** I think we need to decide what this tag shall be about and fix the questions associated to it.

**Then** We need to decide on a clear tag for questions related to compilation from vim. Of course there is the [quickfix](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quickfix) tag. As an experienced Vim user I know the feature, and I'm able to find the tag. But what about new comers? Can we really expect them to find the right tag? Given all the question mis-associated to [compile-vim](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/compile-vim) I doubt so.

Shouldn't we have a `compile-from-vim` tag that acts as a synonym to [quickfix](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quickfix)? Or should we have yet another tag?

Comment: Tags, tags, tags… [I'm all for using them, and doing it well!](https://vi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1499/10604) I know there are some other opinions, which I'll leave here: e.g., [Martin](https://vi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1456/10604)

Comment: I think people *can* have expertise for these kind of things @D.BenKnoble; so IMHO a tag like this would make sense. [tag:makeprg] *kind-of* covers it, but it's perhaps a bit limited?

Answer (score 3):

> But what about new comers? Can we really expect them to find the right tag?  > Given all the question mis-associated to [compile-vim](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/compile-vim) I doubt so.

In my experience people don't read tag descriptions, so having two tags which are similar in name but actually very different is not going to help that. I mean, how many questions about running Vim on Microsoft Windows ([microsoft-windows](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-windows)) are currently mistagged with [vim-windows](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vim-windows)?

[compile-from-vim](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/compile-from-vim) seems a bit overly long/waffling to me for a tag name. [makeprg](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/makeprg) is closely related to what you're suggesting; perhaps we can also add a [compiler](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/compiler) which is a bit broader and also covers `:compiler` and such (could even alias them, maybe?)

But if we don't retag or rename [compile-vim](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/compile-vim) people will keep mistagging these questions; I think it would make sense to rename [compile-vim](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/compile-vim) to something like `building-vim`, or maybe just retag all the existing [compile-vim](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/compile-vim) questions to the already existing [installing](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/installing) tag?

Comment: Indeed, if there is a `installing`  tag, it seems like a good candidate for absorbing  `compile-vim`.