# Can we add the "lambda" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Functional programming is a thing in many languages today, and higher order functions are its masterpieces. And higher order functions demand functions to be objects that can be passed around, aka lambdas.

Since `vimscript` and `vim9script` both have lambdas, as well as functions like `filter` and `map` taking other functions, can we have a [lambda](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lambda) tag?

Here's a list of questions that makes reference to lambdas in Vim:

- [How can I define vim9 functions and vim9 lambdas in a vim9 script?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/36829/how-can-i-define-vim9-functions-and-vim9-lambdas-in-a-vim9-script/36830?noredirect=1#comment66083_36830)
- [All these questions/answers](https://vi.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bvimscript%5D+%22lambda%22)

Comment: Tags should naturally be added as questions with that category are introduced and need to be grouped. Maybe you can either add to this question a list of questions that fit that tag or make an answer with the same info. That will help show how you propose to use the tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My personal opinion, with influence from [Martin](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/51/martin-tournoij)'s [comments on previous tag-related things](https://vi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1456/10604): I don't see vimscript lambdas being a high-signal technical subject in which you can have expertise, and I find it unlikely that people are trying to connect to questions specifically about vimscript lambdas.

From a community perspective: if people want the tag, so it shall be :)

---

A technical nit: "lambda" is not the name for a function that can be "passed around." There are lots of concepts at play here:

- A "lambda" is a (syntactic) expression whose value is a function, sometimes called a closure when it also creates a lexical (or dynamic) closure, which most do.
- A language has "first-class functions" when a function is a valid kind of *value*, for example, when it is possible to construct functions and pass them as arguments.
- First-class functions are used by most kinds of functional programming, as noted, usually as arguments to higher-order functions. These arguments *need not be lambdas* (if the language supports proper first-class functions). Other kinds of syntactic expressions can evaluate to functions; lambdas are but one kind.